# How to package/send a program (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013

I would like to send a program I've been working on to a friend so that he can test it for me, but I don't know exactly how to do so. Should I just put the release folder in a .zip file and send it to him like that, and tell him to run the .exe? Or is there an installer that I can sort of "*package*" it in?

I've created a C++ program using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you zip it up they may need additional runtime libraries installed ([VC redistributables](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)) on their OS. You can also use  [installer software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) to help manage this. Which one you choose is up to you but zipping it up may be the easiest way if they're willing to manually install the required VC Redistributable package. Just make sure you include *all* dependencies your application requires to run.

Keep in mind that the debug version of the VC runtime is **not** part of the redistributable package and cannot (legally) be deployed. You will need to send them Release mode versions of the application.

Comment: Very interesting. Do you have an installer software in particular (for Windows) you recommend?

Comment: Nope. But you can check/ask over at the Stack Exchange [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using

```
gisthub.com
```

You can easily post loads of code, public/private and can share the link
easily with anyone you like.

Also:

You could send the actual file of your program to him,
but for him to use it he would have to have the EXACT same
integrated development environment(IDE) as you.
For Example:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
```

Comment: This seems cool, but I was actually hoping for a way so that I could send an installer wizard to my friend.